# How to add vector images support for ImageChooserBlock in Wagtail CMS?

Tags: django, validation, svg, model, wagtail

I want to be able to upload `.svg` files in `ImageChooserBlock`. By default, `.svg` format fails validation when uploading via Wagtail's admin panel. (Vector graphics is not supported in `wagtail_images`).

I'm using Wagtail 1.12.3.

Comment: Relevant discussion: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/1708

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by installing and configuring [wagtail_svgmap](https://github.com/City-of-Helsinki/wagtail-svgmap) extension for Wagtail CMS.